# Including a new module in node_modules in AWS Cloud9

Tags: node.js, socket.io, aws-cloud9

I am using AWS cloud9 to create a webserver. I created an environment there. It has my server.js and index.html page. I want to include socket.IO module in the node_modules. But I am not able to install the socket.io package in the AWS cloud9. 
Can anyone tell where and how to include the package there?

[image]

Comment: AWS cloud9 official doc suggests the way to include packages.
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cloud9/latest/user-guide/sample-nodejs.html

Comment: Yes, I have gone through this. Can you tell where to type the command `npm i socket.io` in this Cloud9 IDE?

Comment: Oh yeah! I got it now. In the AWS Cloud9 IDE, on the menu bar, choose Run, Run Configurations, New Run Configuration.

On the [New] - Idle tab, choose Runner: Auto, and then choose Node.js.Type npm i socket.io